# log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed with no proper message under java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, log4j

I am not understanding the error in my log4j.xml. Also I do not see much details under the filenotfoundexception to find the proper issue. Can you please check into the below code and point where I am wrong?

```
 #Application Logs
log4j.logger.devpinoyLogger=DEBUG, dest1, stdout



log4j.additivity.devpinoyLogger=false
log4j.additivity.initLogger=false

#file appender
log4j.appender.dest1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dest1.maxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.dest1.maxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.dest1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c %m%n
log4j.appender.dest1.File=${catt.log}
#do not append the old file. Create a new log file everytime
log4j.appender.dest1.Append=false

#console appender
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.initLogger=DEBUG, init

log4j.appender.init=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.init.maxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.init.maxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.init.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.init.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c %m%n
log4j.appender.init.File=C:\\CATT\\Application.txt
#log4j.appender.init.File=${init.log}
#do not append the old file. Create a new log file everytime
log4j.appender.init.Append=false
```

Exception is :

```
    log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:289)
        at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:167)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:163)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:256)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:132)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:96)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:654)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:612)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:533)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:417)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:441)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:470)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:122)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104).
```

For the line:

```
Logger.getLogger("initLogger");
```